# Strunk and White progress link leads to 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page

When I access the Strunk and White 'badge count progress' button on meta, it leads to the [404 "page not found"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts) page for the low quality review queue

[image]

Comment: What URL are you seeing on the 404 page? When I just tried it, it led me to [the LQP review queue](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts), which doesn't exist on meta. Sounds like it might be a SE-wide problem. (Also duplicated on meta ELU, but not on meta Worldbuilding.)

Comment: I duplicated this on meta.EE.SE. On a site where I do not have this badge on the main site (TeX.SE) there's no "Go get it" link. So maybe the intention is to have no link, but the per-site metas have the link anyway? Might be worth posting this on Meta.SE.

Comment: I have also reproduced this here and on M&TV. I do not see a "Go get it" link only when there is *no progress* toward the S&W badge on the main site. Also, I agree with Rand that since the main links take you the LQP review page it is probably a SE-wide problem.

Comment: @Null Could the criterion be not "having earned the S&W badge on main" but instead "having enough rep to view the Low Quality Posts review queue"? This would fit together with the fact that the LQP queue is where the "Go get it" button seems to link to.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yes, the low quality queue. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts

Comment: Weird flex, but ok.

Answer (score 4):

The button is gone, so this is no longer a problem:

> [image]